# How to put an image in a react-native drawer?

Tags: react-native

I am using the `@react-navigation/native` library. I have a drawer with some screens in them. I can click on the links and navigate to the appropriate screen. I would like to place an image above the links in the drawer. I am using the property `drawerContent` to do this. However, when I do this it removes the links. I cant figure out how to have the links and the image above the links in the drawer. What is the correct way to do this? Here is some code for my drawer with the `drawerContent`.

```js
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Screen1"
         drawerContent={() => (
           <View style={{height: "10%"}}>
             <Image
             style={{width: "90%"}}
             resizeMode="contain"
             source={require('../../../assets/new-logo/textSide.png')}/>
           </View>
         )}
        screenOptions={ ({navigation}) => ({
          drawerContainerStyle: {paddingTop: 100},
          drawerLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: KbStyles.properties.drawerLabelSize,
            color: "white"
          },
          headerTintColor: {color: KbStyles.properties.white},
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: KbStyles.properties.black
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: KbStyles.properties.headerSize,
            color: "white"
          },
          headerLeft: () => (
    
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => {navigation.toggleDrawer()}}>
              <Image
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{height: "50%"}}
                source={require("../../../assets/menu.png")}
              />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          ),
          drawerActiveBackgroundColor : KbStyles.properties.red,
          drawerActiveTintColor: KbStyles.properties.white,
          drawerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            width: 300
    
          }
        })}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen2 component={Screen2} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
    
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Here is also an image showing what I would like to achieve.

[image: what i would like]

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Under the Drawer.Navigator you can use drawerContent as,

```
 drawerContent={(props)=> {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                    <ImageBackground source={require("../Assets/Vrda1img2.jpg")} style={{justifyContent:"space-between",alignItems:"center",padding:20,marginBottom:20,backgroundColor:"rgb(0,0,0)",borderBottomWidth:2,borderColor:Colors.secondary}} imageStyle=
                        {{opacity:0.4}}>
                        <Image source={require("../Assets/vector.png")} style={{width:70,height:70,borderRadius:35,borderWidth:2,borderColor:Colors.white}}/>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:20,fontWeight:"bold",color:Colors.white}}>{userDetail?userDetail.name:"Not Available"}</Text>
                        <Text style={{color:Colors.light}}>{userDetail?userDetail.email:"Not Available"}</Text>
                    </ImageBackground>
                    <DrawerItemList {...props}/>
                </DrawerContentScrollView>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{logout()}} style={{position:"relative",right:0,left:0,bottom:5,backgroundColor:"rgb(231,230,230)"}}>
                    <Text style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(162,160,160,0.29)",width:"100%",height:40,textAlign:"center",paddingTop:8}}><SimpleLineIcons name={"logout"} size={15} color={Colors.primary}/> LogOut</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    } 
 }
```

I give you the reference of my code where you can add Image under the Image background you can also use Uri to add an image as a link.